# Parsing binary VTK

Tags: vtk, paraview

[This paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/cnm.3235) provides a link to 10 3D models contained in [binary VTK files](https://doi.org/10.6084/m9.figshare.8047742.v2), but I can't open them in ParaView (tried several versions from `2.x` to `5.x` on Linux and Windows, 32 and 64 bits) and other applications for VTK files.
I'd appreciate any help with opening them. Below is what I could find out.

ParaView reports an unknown keyword. From VTK 4 specification [PDF file](https://vtk.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/file-formats.pdf) we see that after "POINTS N float" follows `N` triples of floats. I suppose size of (float) is 4 thus we get a data block of `N * 3 * 4` bytes. After this data block we expect a new keyword (CELLS or something else), but no keyword there, just another several KB of binary data.
Another weird thing is that the last block (CELL_TYPES) should consist of integers. Integer in binary form is supposed to be 2, 4 or 8 bytes (common is 4), BUT we see sequences of three zero-bytes followed by pairs of ASCII chars with codes (13,10) which obviously indicate new line, thus integer value is coded with three bytes? I'm very confused.

Comment: As it looks like the files are ill-formed (I also tried), I suggest you to contact the paper authors.

Comment: @NicoVuaille Thank you for looking into this. Yes, I guess the files are ill-formed.